# Issue from HTTPS installation in node js

Tags: node.js

I am using https package for running the program in https. I have proper ssl certificate and private key and bundle file. all these files included in my code. This https program also running without error. But when I connect front end to node js it doesn't connected. The error is "504 gateway Time out". Where is I make error? I host my code in azure.

```
const https = require('https');

//path for private key and certificate
let privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key','utf8');
let certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt','utf8');

var credential = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate,
  };

   var server = https.createServer(credential, app)
   server.listen('8443',function() {
    console.log('Listening on https://localhost:' + 8443);
  });
```

Comment: Are you sure your front end app is on the same machine and same network that your nodeJS server ? If not, have you a firewall enable ? If you not precise the hostname, you will be able to only accept local connexion (`127.0.0.1`)

Comment: if its use http server working fine but i move to https its did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback

So if you do not declare `host` for your `server.listen()` the default host should be `0.0.0.0` instead.

Comment: So what i do for fix this

Answer (score 0):

If you need to listen of specific address, you must define it after the port.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
}).listen(8443, "0.0.0.0");
```

Your front server need to be on the same network subnet as your API.

Comment: i have to use own certificate not a self signed certificate